# Regex for each object in jquery array

Tags: jquery, regex

When a button is clicked, it's `data-marker` attribute is added to (or removed from) the array `markers`.

So for example if I've clicked all three of the buttons - `Apples`, `Oranges` and `Pears`, the `markers` array will read `[Apples,Oranges,Pears]`. This is working fine.

I then want to do a new regex **for each object in the array**, but I don't know how.

Currently when I call the regex it just does the whole array as a string, and the resulting regex looks like this:

```
/Apples,Oranges,Pears/gi
```

But I want it to do a new regex for each object in the array, like this:

```
/Apples/gi
/Oranges/gi
/Pears/gi
```

How can I do this? Working snippet of what I have so far below:

```js
  // Create new array to store data-marker values
  var markers = [];

  // Declare global variable for use later
  var qsRegexx;
  
  // When user clicks any button having class 'z-btn-i'...
  var $quickfilter = $('.z-btn-i').click(function() {
    
    // Store some more variables
    var $this = $(this);
    var datamarker = $this.attr('data-marker');
    
    // Add or remove the value of the button's data-marker attribute to/from the array 'markers'
    if (markers.indexOf(datamarker)!=-1) {
        markers.splice(markers.indexOf(datamarker),1);
    } else {
        markers.push(datamarker);
    }
    
    console.log(markers);
    console.log(qsRegexx);
    
    // THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK
    // I want to do a new regex for each object in the array 'markers', not one regex of all of them together...
    qsRegexx = new RegExp(markers, 'gi');
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="z-btn-i" data-marker="Apples">Apples</button>
<button class="z-btn-i" data-marker="Pears">Pears</button>
<button class="z-btn-i" data-marker="Oranges">Oranges</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop over the array of records create a new regex for each of them individually

[.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
const regexMakers = markers.map(marker => new RegExp(marker, 'gi'));
console.log(regexMakers);
```

---

```js
  // Create new array to store data-marker values
  var markers = [];

  // Declare global variable for use later
  var qsRegexx;
  
  // When user clicks any button having class 'z-btn-i'...
  var $quickfilter = $('.z-btn-i').click(function() {
    
    // Store some more variables
    var $this = $(this);
    var datamarker = $this.attr('data-marker');
    
    // Add or remove the value of the button's data-marker attribute to/from the array 'markers'
    if (markers.indexOf(datamarker)!=-1) {
        markers.splice(markers.indexOf(datamarker),1);
    } else {
        markers.push(datamarker);
    }
    
    console.log(markers);
    
    const regexMakers = markers.map(marker => new RegExp(marker, 'gi'));
    console.log(regexMakers);

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="z-btn-i" data-marker="Apples">Apples</button>
<button class="z-btn-i" data-marker="Pears">Pears</button>
<button class="z-btn-i" data-marker="Oranges">Oranges</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Tushar - this returns an array with the regex expressions for each object in the array, yay :)

What if I want to run each of the regex from that array afterwards like this?

    $this.text().match(regexMakers);

This doesn't seem to work... ^

Comment: @Teebling you can do `regexMakers.map(rx => rx.exec($this.text()));`

Comment: Hey @Tushar, thanks - could you please tell me how I could integrate that into the below function?

function() {
    var myResult = regexMakers ? $this.text().match(regexMakers) : true;
    return myResult;
}